# Sketchables in WPF with .NET 4, can't load System.Core version=2.0.5.0

Tags: wpf, silverlight, sketchflow

Sketchflow newbie (couple days), WPF newbie (few weeks).

Workspace details:

WinXP, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, Expression Studio Ultimate (using Expression Blend 4 with SketchFlow). Downloaded the [Sketchables 0.9 release](http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/07/public-sketchables-preview-release) and built a release version (Debug version is already built).

Issue details:

Start up Expression Blend 4, create a WPF Sketchflow project. Build it (successful). Add references to *either* the release *or* debug versions of the Sketchables library (in the Desktop, rather than the SL folder) and try to build again. The build fails with error:

```
Unknown build error, 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXX' or ore of its dependencies. The local assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'
```

Now, I've seen some issues with a similar error, specifically a couple of issues where the problem was caused by trying to load a Silverlight control in a WPF project. However, I'm not knowledgeable enough to know if it's related. On a hunch, I tried a Silverlight project. Sure enough, building a Silverlight Sketchflow project and adding the Sketchables library builds cleanly.

So, the question is this: **Does anyone have any ideas about what's actually causing this error within the Sketchables source, on pointers on how to track it down so I can work on it and get a clean library build for WPF?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have identified the cause of the problem, the assembly you are trying to reference in your WPF project was compiled for Silverlight (the 2.0.5.0 version number is a giveaway that it is Siverlight).

You might want to check with the author of the controls to see if there is a way to compile it for WPF.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. Thought maybe I was missing something. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Chuck's right. The Sketchables.Common dll is a Silverlight class library. Easy way to fix is to create a Sketchables.Common.WPF project and make it a regular class library. Copy over the classes from the SL library project, compile, and then change the reference in Sketchables.WPF to point to Sketchables.Common.WPF instead of Sketchables.Common. Your Blend project should now build.

A more advanced way is to share both Common projects to same files, but I won't go into that here. Search for share (link) files between projects and you'll find answers for that.